# php sessions not working correctly

Tags: php, session

Hello i am having problems holding sessions from page to page, code worked on my previous servers running php5 but not on my recent server, i am wondering whether its a bug?

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['session'] = $_POST['session'];

header("location: www.mysite.com/page1.php");
?>


<?php
session_start();

echo "Good morning" . $_SESSION['session'];   //returns empty session always.
?>
```

ANy ideas?  session is held on first page but not on the second.

Comment: Where does `$_POST['session']` come from ?

Comment: Did you actually send a value `session` in `$_POST`?

Comment: what does a `var_dump($_POST['session']);` returns in the first page?

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);` on the second page

Comment: Error reporting? What do the returned headers look like? (See `wget -S ...`). And what does `print_r($_SERVER);` say? Most likely it's yet another case of ["but it worked on the other server?!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: If the problem can not be solved anyhow, try to create a new fresh file, write the script again and execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you missed it, make sure you do a `session_start()` at every page you're using the `$_SESSION` variable.

You should check your php.ini file and see what's going on.

Make sure `session.use_cookies = 1` and `session.save_handler = files`.

Use this test page to see whether it's a general PHP problem or just your code.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION)){
        echo "Session variable exists<br/>";

        if(!isset($_SESSION['test'])){
            $_SESSION['test'] = "Success!";
            echo "Variable has been set, refresh the page and see if stored it properly.";
        }else{
            echo $_SESSION['test'];
        }
    }else{
        echo "No session variable has been created.";
    }
?>
```

If that worked, then it's got to do with your code.

If you're setting your session variable to `$_POST['session']` am I to assume you submitted a form with an input with the name `session`?

This setup *should* work.

index.php

```
<form action='page0.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='session' value='SPAAAAACE' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Page0.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['session'] = $_POST['session'];

    header("location: www.mysite.com/page1.php");
?>
```

Page1.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    echo "Good morning" . $_SESSION['session'];
?>
```

---

### For completeness and debugging purposes

In case you are using cookie-less sessions, you have to manually add the [`SID` (session id)](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) to the header redirect like this

```
header("location: www.mysite.com/page.php?".htmlspecialchars(SID));
```

---

If the problem still persists, it could be a permission issue.
Maybe you're not allowed to read the session file stored on the server?

**Update: OP commented that it was a permission issue and the problem is now resolved**

Comment: Hello i found the problem thanks to you, it was a permissions issue.

Comment: @user1302936 Hah, I had the same problem at work a couple of months ago. Didn't have admin clearance. Anyway, good thing you were able to solve it. Would you please mark my answer as "Accepted", it's the green check sign at the top left of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on error reporting temperately with:
`error_reporting(E_ALL)` This may spit out an error related to your problem. Most likely an undefined index session notice.

You should always have a check in place on Super Globals.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['session'] = (isset($_POST['session']))?$_POST['session']:null;

header("Location: www.mysite.com/page1.php");
die;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct though I'm pretty sure $_POST['session'] is empty.

You should try this :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['session'] = 'John Doe';

header("location: www.mysite.com/page1.php");
?>


<?php
session_start();

echo "Good morning" . $_SESSION['session'];   //returns empty session always.
?>
```

To see if this works or not. I guess it will.

IF not, take a look at your cookies, maybe they are disabled.

Then, if it works, I probably because `$_POST['session']` is null or empty, are you sure you posted something like `<input type="text" name="session" />` ?

Comment: ShadowScripter your code functioned correctly but i only have problems reusing sessions on other pages.

Comment: cx42net Nope no session held using above code, i will check my php.ini

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the session id with the redirect.

Also make sure you use session_start() at the top of EVERY page that needs a session

Comment: Session id is required if cookies are disabled. Maybe it's the case for him.

Answer (score -1):

First try using

```
<?php session_start();
```

instead of

```
<?php
session_start();
```

If the problem still exists, then open your script in **Netbeans** editor and see whether any unexpected characters found at very beginning of the the script.

In addition, please make sure that $_POST['session'] has a value to assign in $_SESSION['session'].

Comment: It doesn't change anything, the code is the same from the compiler perspective.

Comment: I know, but depending on scripting environment (os and ide) sometimes few unexpected characters inserted into the script which does not shown in many editors. Still sometimes I face the problem.

Answer (score -3):

You will have to call

```
session_start();
```

on the first line of every page you want to retain the session in

Comment: Yes - as you can see in the question, he did.