# Array will not save into SESSION PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code.

```
$getPoetry['poet'] = $_SESSION[$member]['filters']['newspaper'] = array(
    '$in' => $allFollowing
);
```

`$getPoetry['poet']`  has the complete array inside while  `$_SESSION[$member]['filters']['newspaper']`  does not.

What might be the problem?

When I print the array  `$_SESSION[$member]`  exists but it's a key with an empty array

Comment: Have you initialised `$member`?

Comment: Have you tried print_r($_SESSION[$member]['filters']['newspaper']);
or print_r($_SESSION); ?

Comment: Yes. And I get [nameOfMember] => Array ( ).

Comment: have you started session by writing session_start(); beginning of page

Comment: @Joshua have you tried my example? is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one**

```
<?php   
    session_start();

    // create an array
    $my_array=array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'bird', 'crocodile', 'wombat', 'koala', 'kangaroo');

    // put the array in a session variable
    $_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;

    // a little message to say we have done it
    echo 'Putting array into a session variable';

    // loop through the session array with foreach
    foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
        {
        // and print out the values
        echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
        }
    ?>
```

**Your example I have given some value to the variable what ever you used**

```
<?php
session_start();
$member = 'new';
$allFollowing = 'follower';
$getPoetry['poet'] = $_SESSION[$member]['filters']['newspaper'] = array('$in' => $allFollowing);
print_r($_SESSION[$member]['filters']['newspaper']);
print_r($getPoetry);
?>
```

**@Yogesh Suthar case he missed key and 0 should not be in the sessions first key check that too**

```
<?php   
session_start();
$abcd = $_SESSION['test']['filters']['newspaper'] = array('test'=>"abcd");
print_r($_SESSION['test']['filters']['newspaper']);
print_r($abcd);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working properly. I think you haven't start the session use `session_start();` at top of page

```
session_start();

$abcd = $_SESSION[0]['filters']['newspaper'] = array("abcd");

print_r($_SESSION[0]['filters']['newspaper']);
print_r($abcd);
```

output as below

```
Array ( [0] => abcd ) Array ( [0] => abcd )
```

Comment: Yeah I am getting $_SESSION[0] but its empty.

Comment: @Joshua refer his link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942907/php-sessions-not-working-correctly

Comment: If I do $_SESSION[$member]['news'] the array saves inside but if I do $_SESSION[$member]['filters']['news'] the array DOES NOT get saved.

Comment: @Joshua, maybe you meant `['newspaper']` at the end?

Comment: @Joshua I have given you example below have looked to that?